# ORPG Engine Development, structuring the code (C++, 2D)

Tags: c++, 2d, game-engine

I've been working on a game 2d ORPG Engine with a friend of mine, however we're having some troubles organizing and structuring the code.

I could use some pointers, guides, tutorials, etc. on how to keep the code flexible, extendible and maintainable.

Thanks for your time, Xeross

Comment: I don't want to sound condescending, but with the info you are giving us, you could just aswell type "refactoring" into Google. Which I recommend anyway. Seriously though.. use Google. You will come up with books like "Code Complete" and then go from there.

Comment: Blub's entirely right. You need something more specific.

Comment: I guess you're right, it's a bit vague, guess I'll have to look at some game coding books, etc. and perhaps see if I can implement something like MVC or another design pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just mark this as correct as the subject is too vague, my apologies, thanks for everyone replying though :)

Answer (score 1):

One of my preferred books:

C++ Coding Standards by Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu,

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll take a look at it.